# A RecursiveParentChildIterator -- like the RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Tags: php, recursion, tree, spl, adjacency-list

There are tons of examples of using the RecursiveIterator to flatten a tree structure.. but what about using it to explode a tree structure?

Is there an elegant way to use this, or some other SPL library to recursively build a tree (read: turn a flat array into array of arbitrary depth) given a table like this:

```
SELECT id, parent_id, name FROM my_tree
```

**EDIT:**
You know how you can do this with Directories?

```
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/var/www/images");
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {
    echo $file . PHP_EOL;
}
```

.. What if you could do something like this:

```
$it = new RecursiveParentChildIterator($result_array);
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $group) {
    echo $group->name . PHP_EOL;
    // this would contain all of the children of this group, recursively
    $children = $group->getChildren();
}
```

**:END EDIT**

Comment: You might want to give an input/output example

Comment: @Gordon Really, the i/o could be anything (mysqli result => associative array / some object.. whatever) -- what I'm really looking for is an elegant way, using SPL rather than some homemade stuff, to convert the results of the above query to an object or array that understands, for example, that "row 3 is a child of row 7 because (parent_id in row 3) == (id in row 7)".

Comment: @Stephen the reason why I suggested giving an example was more due to the term tree not being too well known among the PHP crowd, but if you give an example, people might come up with a solution, even if they don't know they just worked with a tree.

Comment: @Gordon Good point.. that could be why I have so much trouble finding good examples too :-P The site that explains the process @Stefan uses below has some arrays that demonstrate its output ( http://bit.ly/ajCfyU ).

Comment: Just as a side note: the reason I'm hesitant to specify a desired output is that I've been somewhat dissatisfied with all the solutions I've come up with for managing hierarchies. I'm anxious to hear what processes others have come up with.

Comment: I added some stuff that shows what I have in mind, but have not yet been able to successfully implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though not SPL, but you can use references (`&`) build up a tree with native PHP:

```
// untested
$nodeList = array();
$tree     = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $nodeList[$row['id']] = array_merge($row, array('children' => array()));
}
foreach ($nodeList as $nodeId => &$node) {
    if (!$node['parent_id'] || !array_key_exists($node['parent_id'], $nodeList)) {
        $tree[] = &$node;
    } else {
        $nodeList[$node['parent_id']]['children'][] = &$node;
    }
}
unset($node);
unset($nodeList);
```

Comment: This seems to be the best solution that I have come across so far (they use the same process here: http://bit.ly/4IyIBR ). I appreciate its sneaky way of avoiding recursion -- a process I find is best reserved for some sort of a reusable pattern, such as those provided in the SPL library.